# positioning elements, i want to position the elements like this picture:- but i dont know how

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

[image]
i want to align the elements in the `#gameInpBox` like the image billow

```css
body{
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Signika Negative', sans-serif;
  background-color: #252525;
  color: #f8f9fa;
}



.dim {
  
  background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.6);
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 30;
  display: block;
}

#gameInpBox{
  z-index: 31;
  height: 40vh;
  width: 50vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: #adb5bd;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 54px 55px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px -12px 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 4px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17) 0px 12px 13px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px -3px 5px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.form{
  
}

label{
  text-align: left;
}

input{
  width: 10vw;
}

select{
  width: 8vw;
}

#Add{
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  
  font-family: 'Signika Negative', sans-serif;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: .375rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2vh;

  letter-spacing: -.01em;
  line-height: 1.3;
  /* padding: 1rem 1.25rem; */
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transform: translateZ(0) scale(1);
  transition: transform .2s;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 5vh;
  right: 2%;
  bottom: 1vh;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}



#cancel{
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  
  font-family: 'Signika Negative', sans-serif;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: .375rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2vh;

  letter-spacing: -.01em;
  line-height: 1.3;
  /* padding: 1rem 1.25rem; */
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transform: translateZ(0) scale(1);
  transition: transform .2s;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 5vh;
  right: 24%;
  bottom: 1vh;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}



#close{
  background: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #252525;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Mono&family=Signika+Negative:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Mono&family=Signika+Negative:wght@300&display=swap');
    </style>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Overwatch Tracker</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dim" id="dim">
        <div id="gameInpBox">
            <button id="close">✖</button>
            <div id="inps">
                <form class="form">
                    <label for="dmg">Damage delt:</label><input type="text" id="dmgSEL" name="dmg">
                    <label for="heal">Healing done:</label><input type="text" id="healSEL" name="heal"><br>
                    <label for="resault">Resault:</label><select name="resault" id="resaultSEL">
                        <option value="Win">Win</option>
                        <option value="Draw">Draw</option>
                        <option value="Loss">Loss</option>                        
                    </select>
                    <label for="role">Role:</label><select name="role" id="roleSEL">
                        <option value="DPS">DPS</option>
                        <option value="Support">Support</option>
                        <option value="Tank">Tank</option>                        
                    </select>
                    <label for="map">Map:</label><select name="map" id="mapSEL">
                        <option value="Illios">Illios</option>
                        <option value="Kings-row">Kings row</option>
                        <option value="NQS">NQS</option>                        
                    </select>
                    
                </form>
                <button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
                <button id="Add">Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  
    
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please check the guidelines for posting (relevant) "*[mcve]*" code, there is a *lot* in your posted code that seems to be irrelevant to creating the alignment you show in the illustration in your question. You've posted two demos - and, genuinely, thank you for showing the initiative to post code in your question - unless they're both relevant (if they are, explain how and why) then delete one, and edit the other to show your best attempts at solving your problem and minimise the code.

Comment: i didn't know that the first one was added, sorry about that and thanks for telling me

Comment: You're welcome, thank you for editing. But you need to look at the code still present in the question: the JavaScript has nothing to do with the alignment you're struggling with. The `:hover` based CSS rules have nothing to do with the alignment. Anything that's in your code that can be removed should be removed until only the absolute smallest amount of code necessary to illustrate your problem remains. As you work through this there's a good chance you'll realise what was "wrong" with your code that complicated things for you, and if not: then we can help if we're not parsing the whole site.

Comment: i edited it so only the box i want shows up is that okay ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at your code, it looks like you can do this by adding a display value of flex with a flex-direction of column to your class "form".  This will make everything flow top to bottom.

```css
.form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Then you will have to get your label and input on the same line.  I believe this can be done with float, though I might wrap each in a div with a flex display so I can move them around as needed on the line. If you set a width on your .form div, justify-content: space-between will push the label to the left and the input field to the right, as shown in your wireframe.

```css
.form-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-wrapper">
  <label for="dmg">Damage delt:</label>
  <input type="text" id="dmgSEL" name="dmg">
</div>
```

Awesome idea, good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you so much man i was stuck on this for 2 days i really appreciate it!